# Download Data from HTML table to excel

Tags: php, excel

I have a table, constructed in PHP that displays results from a mysql table.

Like so:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey");

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Question 1</th>
            <th>Question 2</th>
            <th>Question 3</th>
            <th>Question 4</th>
            <th>Question 5</th>
            <th>Question 6</th>
            <th>Question 7</th>
            <th>Question 8</th>
            <th>Question 9</th>
            <th>Question 10</th>
            <th>Question 11</th>
            <th>Question 12</th>
            <th>Question 13</th>
            <th>Question 14</th>
            <th>eMail</th>
            </tr>";

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question1'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question2'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question3'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question4'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question5'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question6'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question7'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question8'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question9'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question10'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question11'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question12'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question13'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Question14'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['eMail'] . "</td>";              
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

What I want to do is output this table into an excel file, without any source code, or table tags. Is there a way I can do this? I've been overwhelmed with information on the internet and not quite sure what I need.

If possible I'd prefer to do this with just PHP, and without any additional libraries.

Comment: Check out PEAR's Spreadsheet Excel Writer http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/ It should do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to download an Excel file using your PHP script (ie- the PHP outputs a .xls file) or do you want it to produced HTML output that you can copy/paste into an Excel file without losing formatting?

If the former, look into [this nifty tool](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

If you just want it to produce HTML that you can copy/paste into Excel, so long as your table is properly formatted (and from your source code, it looks like you need to add a </tr> at the end of your while loop) then you should just be able to [drag and drop it](http://www.mrkent.com/tools/converter/)

Alternatively, Excel **should** be smart enough to recognize HTML tables so long as there is no <html> tag encapsulating it. [this article](http://www.greggriffiths.org/webdev/both/excel/) explains the process, but essentially you can send an Excel file (as per the first "nifty tool" suggestion) with just:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
echo "
<table>
    ...
</table>";
```

Comment: Hi steven, I've downloaded the 'nifty tool' :) because I want to use my PHP script to output the excel file, but I'm slightly lost as to what to do next with it. Any tips?

Comment: Installing it is just a matter of copying the contents of /Classes to anywhere on your website. After that you require("PHPExcel.php") and create a new PHPExcel() (it's a class, so just $myObject = new PHPExcel()). You can change cells with $myObject->setCellValue('A1',"value");

Comment: Look at /Tests/01simple.php for a sample Excel sheet.

Comment: @TaraWalsh Look in the /Tests directory of the PHPExcel download for examples of using the library

Answer (score 2):

Well outputting Excel native format would be quite complex.. thats why there are libraries for it. CSV on the other hand is easy and Excel can read that.

```
$filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/test.csv';
$file = fopen($filePath, '-w');

while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)))
{
  fputcsv($file, $row);
}

// rewind both pointers
mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);
fseek($file, 0);

// add headers
$rowForHeaders = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
fputcsv($file, array_keys($rowforHeaders));

fclose($file);


// to send the file via the http response
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="mytable.csv"');
header('Content-length: '.filesize($filePath));
print file_get_contents($filePath);
exit;
```

Comment: According to http://www.greggriffiths.org/webdev/both/excel/, you can just output an HTML table with the proper header and Excel will read it

Comment: Hi, I get the following errors when I run the above....Warning: fopen(C:\Users\TaraW\Desktop) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No error in..
Warning: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.... 
Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.... 
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...

Comment: PHP has to have write access to the directory/file... By default it shouldnt have this access to your Desktop. try using your systems temporary dir... you can get this in PHP by `sys_get_temp_dir()`. I updated my example...

Comment: Excel is capable of reading HTML, but it will offer a warning when loading the file.

Comment: @prodigitalson Fantastic solution, just what I needed. Thanks for posting. BTW, fantastic nick. Wish I could +2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use csv (comma separated values) which can be opened by excel:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo '"'. $row['Question1'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question2'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question3'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question4'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question5'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question6'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question7'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question8'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question9'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question10'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question11'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question12'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question13'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['Question14'] . '";';
  echo '"'. $row['eMail'] . '"\n';         
}
```

Comment: do you know what PHP I use once I do this?