# Need to Export tabular data into Excel (xlsx) format by javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel, xlsx, js-xlsx

I want to export my data (which reside on the Page) into excel (xlsx) format. I have gone through couple of available libraries but none of them actually worked or helped me to achieve my requirement. Below are the required things which I want to do while export:

- Header column (First row of the exported xlsx file) should be bold which clearly state it as header.
- Every column should be defined which the type of data like date column, string column, number column.
- I can set the width of the columns, when opening the exported xlsx file (optional thing, if it is achievable)

I have gone through various JS based framework but most of them are providing support for xls file not for xlsx. But there are some which provides xlsx support like [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), but there is no good documentation available to do that or how to achieve the excel export functionality with my requirements.

I have also looked into one more xlsx export framework ([exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs)) which is very good with the documentation, but I doubt it is not available outside of nodejs, its a plugin of nodejs thus require nods js to run. Thus its not purely client side or on page side.

Can you please help me to achieve that with java-script.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need JS libraries, just output the page with table and set header to `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8`. Also style the cells using [this formatting](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.co.at/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html) in order to define excel cell type.

Comment: @skobaljic, Thanks for your suggestion well I'm not aware about that process,Can you please explain this a little bit, means how can I do that. Also will it supports all major browsers. mostly IE, Safari and chrome

Comment: On your Excel download page, first output Excel header, filename and content size, than the HTML table with styles mentioned above and that's it. Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831186/download-data-from-html-table-to-excel#answer-3831294) I found. Further on, it has nothing to do with browsers, but with Excel on your machine. A benefit, since you create this download page, you could add a **pdf** export easily in case you have [webkit html to pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can `SheetJS` `xlsx` library it will more help to you. Here is the example [Table to Excel](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html)

Comment: I'm also pointing to this same framework in my question, this framework is not very detailed in instructions and also it is not fulfilling my requirement bullet points, like header as a bold text,and data type columns definition

Comment: Did you check this https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/README.md

Comment: In the sheetjs xlsx, readme file.. One section is there.. "Workbook / Worksheet / Cell Object Description" in this section it will be explained but it is some what high level. I Searched many libraries for exporting excel, at last I settled with this library.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through with this, but didn't help me.

Comment: @user2809299 Can you provide example. Then I can help you more